# Obtaining the unitary representation of the Lorentz group from infinitesimal transformations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, hilbert-space, group-theory, representation-theory

My knowledge of Lie Groups and Lie Algebras is very limited, even more so when it comes to their representation theories. There is a difference that I can't quite understand, between the representation of inhomogeneous (i.e. translations) and homogeneous (i.e. rotations and boosts) transformations.

For an infinitesimal translation of the form $x'^\mu = x^\mu + \epsilon^\mu$, the operator should be infinitesimally close to the identity (first order in $\epsilon^\mu$),  so that
$$
U = 1 - i\epsilon_{\mu}P^{\mu},
$$
from which we get the finite transformation by composing N of the above and taking $N \rightarrow \infty$, obtaining

$$
U = \exp(-i\epsilon_{\mu}P^{\mu})
$$

The same logic follows for finding the representation of a proper-orthocronous Lorentz transformation. For an infinitesimal one, of the form $\Lambda^\mu_\nu = \delta^\mu_\nu + \omega^\mu_\nu$ ($\omega^\mu_\nu$ infinitesimal and antisymmetric), we should have

$$
U = 1 + \frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}J^{\mu\nu}
$$
from which we can get the finite transformation through the same method as above:
$$
U = \exp\left(\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}J^{\mu\nu}\right)
$$

I'm pretty sure the form of the transformations I wrote above are correct, but there's clearly a missing argument to explain the factor of 1/2 that appears in the latter. Also the sign difference between the two.
If anyone could give further light into the derivation of these expressions, I'd be grateful.

Comment: The factor of $1/2$ is not significant, just a traditional convention (you could just redefine the parameters $\omega_{\mu\nu}$ to get rid of it). It is probably included to account for terms that appear twice, e.g. $\frac{1}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}J^{\mu\nu}= \frac{1}{2}\omega_{01}J^{01}+\frac{1}{2}\omega_{10}J^{10}+\cdots=\omega_{01}J^{01} +\cdots$.

Comment: See this old question of mine: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/342849/

Comment: Thank you, this helped a bunch.